# how to provide animation to image in iphone look like flower

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, core-animation, cocos2d-iphone

I am making an application in iPhone , in that I want to give animation to my image like

Growing from beginning to end and also waving in air, it seems to work like flower, growing from root and also waving in air from left to right smoothly.

I don't know how to perform such kind of animation. 
If any one do have any idea or sample please let me know.

Thanks and regrards Viral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a pretty complex animation. It can be done, but it will be somewhat tedious. Here is [a tutorial by John Blackburn](http://watchingapple.com/2008/04/core-animation-creating-a-jack-in-the-box-with-cakeyframeanimation/) that demonstrates making a jack-in-the-box animation step by step. It would probably be a good starting point for you as you will need to use the same method as John uses.